# Is 12 columns the full page in a Zurb Foundation grid?

Tags: grid, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I am just starting with Foundation 4's grid system and I was under the impression that the 12-column layout was the entire page, but when I opened up Foundation and saw their examples I was confused. Here is the picture [image: Foundation Open screen]

The part under the grid says that it is a 12 column section so where I am confused is the 'Getting Started' sidebar.

1. What is the width of a 12-column section?
2. What is the 'Getting Started' sidebar? (how many columns?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default width of 12-column section in foundation 4 is 1000px but you can change it in _variable.scss file. Find this line:

```
// $row-width: emCalc(1000);
```

change '1000'(for example: 1200) then remove comments and compile Sass files:

```
$row-width: emCalc(1200);
```

If you want see any section create with how many columns use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).
For example, in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSF3P.png) use 3 columns(large-3) for sidebar.

I write an example for Grid Design with foundation:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                Left section with 9 columns and two row.
                First row with one section(12 columns)
                Second row with 2 section(each 6 columns)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                6 columns
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                6 columns
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 columns">
        Right section with 3 columns
    </div>

</div>
```

You can also use sass mixin to create new 'row' classs and new columns classes(for example: 'large-4 columns').

Write this code in your HTML file:

```
<div class="your_custom_row">
    <div class="your_custom_columns_4">
        Define 'your_custom_row' in your sass file: @include grid-row;
        'your_custom_row' equal to 'row columns'

        Define 'your_custom_columns_4' in your sass file: @include grid-column(4);
        'your_custom_columns_4' equal to 'large-4 columns'
    </div>
    <div class="your_custom_columns_8">
        Define 'your_custom_columns_8' in your sass file: @include grid-column(8);
        'your_custom_columns_8' equal to 'large-8 columns'
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        'large-4 columns' equal to 'your_custom_columns_4'
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
        'large-8 columns' equal to 'your_custom_columns_8'
    </div>
</div>
```

and write this code in your sass file:

```
.your_custom_row {
    @include grid-row;
    .your_custom_columns_4 {
        @include grid-column(4);
    }
    .your_custom_columns_8 {
        @include grid-column(8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @parhum, can I have a twelve column section on the left of my page and a three column section on the right of my page in the same row (similar to my picture above)?

Comment: No, you can have 9 columns on the left section and three columns on right section. But you can divide your left section(large-9) to twelve columns again.

Comment: "But you can divide your left section(large-9) to twelve columns again." That part does not make sense to me. Is there a tutorial or another support forum that explains that concept in more detail?

Comment: I edit my answer and write an example for you, is it useful?
Use this code in your HTML files to understand grid design.

Comment: That is very helpful in understanding the concept! Although I am using sass with my grid so I am using mixins. Do you know how to do this with mixins?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you want to do?

Comment: If you look at the bottom of this page it gives a brief example of mixins with foundation :http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Comment: Have you experienced that?

Comment: I edit my answer and add an example for you. Do you need explain it?